# ng-show with filter first returns true, then result of filter

Tags: angularjs

I have a ng-show:

```
<a ng-show="vm.state.task | canFinish : vm.user">Test</a>
```

This results in the a element to be rendered in the browser then if the filter returns a false the element is hidden.

It looks like the `ng-show` first checks the `vm.state.task` (which results in true) then does the filter which could return a false.

But this is not a OR statement, why does the `ng-show` first check the `vm.state.task`?

Comment: you are wrong, it does not work like you described

Comment: why don't you use `&` operator between the two?

Comment: @PetrAveryanov you are correct. The issue was with the filter. Not the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without knowing your "canFinish" function, but: although angular filters are synchronous functions in the first place they may get called multiple times after value changes. So maybe the result changes after the initial call.

Answer (score 0):

In the end the mistake was on my side. The syntax and filter worked as expected and there was a issue in the filter. It was returning a true first but it keeps looping so eventually it would return a false.